# Looping events with Protractor automation framework

Tags: javascript, protractor, dom-events

I am running automated test using protractor - Javascript.. where I am trying to fetch the values from UI which is in table format..

I have written script as below.. where as issue is when I go inside 'i' loop.. it is fetching all the values of 'i' rather first value of 'i' and not proceeding to 'j' loop..

However once `i` loop is completed.. it is properly going to next loop `j` and `k`, where `j` & `k` loops are working as as expected (as per general looping standard in other programming languages)..

```
    this.cate = function () {
    let acct = [];
    return this.getCountOfCate().then((values) => {
        for (let i = 0; i < values; i++) {
            openAccounts.push(browser.findElement(locators.someField).getText());
            this.getRowCount().then((rowValues) => {
                console.log('rowValues is' +rowValues);
                for (let j = 0; j < rowValues; j++) {
                    this.getColumnCount().then((columnValues) => {
                        for (let k = 0; k < columnValues; k++) {
                            acct.push(element.all(classes.accountReports).all(by.css(getAccountCategoryCnt(i))).all(by.css('.title')).get(j).all(by.css('td')).get(k).getText());
                        }
                    })
                }
            });
        }
        return acct;
    });
}
```

Above `cate` is a function, it will be called from other step as promise and expect to return values in array `acct` (Values are returning in this code) after returning I am comparing that with array values..

Only thing is I am not getting in right order as 'i' loop is completing all at once and then proceeding to `j` and `k` loop..

Please suggest what could be the issue here..

Comment: I belive it's overcomplicated. Could you paste HTML structure and tell which values you'd like to retrieve?

Answer (score 5):

Since I have no context on what your table looks like... here's an example of using the map function for the sample HTML snippet. Promises and for loops do not work together which is why we have other methods like `map`, `reduce`, `filter`, and `each`.

HTML snippet example:

```
 <table>
   <tr>
     <td class="name">Foo</td>
     <td class="title">Developer</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td class="name">Bar</td>
     <td class="title">Designer</td>
   </tr>
  </table>
```

You could have a method that uses the `element.all` and [`map`](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.map) functions

```
  // returns a promise of a list of accounts
  getAccounts() => {
    return element.all(by.tagName('tr')).map(elem => {
      let account = new Account();
      let promises = [];
      let tds = elem.all(by.tagName('td'));

      promises.push(tds(by.css('.name')).getText().then(text => {
        account.name = text;
      }));
      promises.push(tds(by.css('.title')).getText().then(text => {
        account.title = text;
      }));

      return Promise.all(promises).then(() => {
        return account;
      });
    });
}
```

So to get the values, you would call:

```
getAccounts().then(accounts => {
  console.log(accounts);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Async looping is hard. My favorite solution for this issue is an `IIFE` ([Instantly Invoked Function Expression][1]). Basically, you create your loop, create the iife, and pass in the index. Here's a basic example.

Here's a basic example:

```
describe('to loop tests', function() {
    var data = ['1', '2', '3'];

    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        // create your iife
        (function(i) { 

            it('pass in the index to an iife', function() {
                console.log('i is: ' + i);
                expect(data[i]).toBe(true); 
            });

        })(i); // pass in index
    }
});
```

That said, that many nested loops is a [code smell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell)... perhaps ask a seperate question; maybe there's a better way to accomplish what you're after.

Comment: thanks.. Problem here is.. I have scope of i Loop till it completes j and k loop.. but however I am fetching a value ('someField' tag in my code above) is the issue.. it should fetch only once when i=0 then should go to j and k loop.. but it is fetching for all i values then again i is assigning to 0 and then looping values for j and k.... I am expecting when i=0 , it should fetch first value of 'someField' then it should go to j=0 then should traverse till it completes all k values. I know it is hard to explain the clear context... but  due to some issues I will not able to provide HTML here.